# No images being compressed using grunt-contrib-imagemin

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I'm having trouble using grunt-contrib-imagemin, insofar as I can't get it to compress any images.

Here's my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here 
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {   
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'css/{base,global,medium,large}.css', // All CSS in the CSS folder
                ],
                dest: 'css/build/production.css',
            }
        },

        cssmin: {
            build: {
                src: 'css/build/production.css',
                dest: 'css/build/production.min.css'
            }
        },

        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'if3/images',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: 'images/build'
                }]
            }
        }       

    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin'); 
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'cssmin', 'imagemin']);

}
```

When I run grunt from the command line, each of concat and cssmin run fine, whereas imagemin - although running without errors -  returns the following message.

```
Running "imagemin:dynamic" (imagemin) task
Minified 0 images (saved 0 B)
```

For info, my folder structure is as follows.

```
if3\
  css\
    *.css
  images\
    *.png
    *.jpg
  js\
    *.js
  node_modules\
    etc.
  Gruntfile.js
  package.json
  *.html
```

The image folder currently contains 7 PNG and 2 JPG files, but I can't figure out why it's not doing anything with them.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `src`-properties in your **concat** and **cssmin** tasks do not contain `if3`. your **imagemin** config does. removing that should probably help...

```
imagemin: {
    dynamic: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'images',
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            dest: 'images/build'
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought, too, but removing that results in the following error.

`Running "imagemin:dynamic" (imagemin) task`
`Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined`

Comment: this seems to happen [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/blob/master/tasks/imagemin.js#L57) which probably means that some of your images is corrupt. this also means, that the config i posted is correct, because imagemin seems to run. run your grunt-task with --verbose flag to get some more information!

Comment: Swapped out my images for some downloaded ones from bbc.co.uk, with the same result. Here's the output of `grunt imagemin --verbose` >

Comment: `Running "imagemin:dynamic" (imagemin) task
Verifying property imagemin.dynamic exists in config...OK
Files: images/_79437129_sister_afp624.jpg -> images/build/_79437129_sister_afp624.jpg
Files: images/_79442199_08283f39-49e3-4346-8a0f-2aae6bd92abf.jpg -> images/build/_79442199_08283f39-49e3-4346-8a0f-2aae6bd92abf.jpg
Files: images/_79452531_79452530.jpg -> images/build/_79452531_79452530.jpg
Options: interlaced, optimizationLevel=3, progressive
Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined`

Comment: looks like a jpegtran issue. maybe you delete `node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin` and reinstall it!? could be that this solves your problem...

Comment: Deleted folder and re-installed but the same issue persists. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: there was a bug with jpegtran-bin and windows. which looks a lot like yours. but this happened on install: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/109. maybe you open an issue on grunt-contrib-imagemin! i would also try to set `progressive` option to `false`. maybe that fixes the issue (with the downside of not getting progressive jpegs)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need use: dynamic {} or static {} and will works perfect.

see: [Grunt imagemin running but not minifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996413/grunt-imagemin-running-but-not-minifying/33041219#33041219)